# How to parse JSR-310 date to Instant?

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing, jsr310, java.time.instant

I'm trying to parse lets say `"2020-01-12+01:00"` with JSR-310 time.

I read it via `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddVV")`, however now if I want to transform that into a Instant via `Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddVV").parse("...")`, it throws where it complains that `time` is null.

Which granted it is, but, I'd like to get Instant from that, i.e. epochMillis, so I can serialize the `long` into a database.

Is there a way around it? Basically I'd like to extend the `"2020-01-12+01:00"` to `"2020-01-12T00:00.000+01:00"` and parse that to Instant as usual

Comment: Do you always want the instant at midnight, in the specified time offset?

Comment: Could your pattern simply be `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`?

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica yes

Comment: @LairdNelson I tried that, but for whatever reason it gives me`zone=null`; but it works if I use my own pattern, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think the answer is `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddVV").parse("...", Instant::from)` but I'm not able to test this at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), specifying [`ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE) format and a [default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) time-of-day (midnight<sup>1</sup>):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter();
Instant instant = Instant.from(formatter.parse("2020-01-12+01:00"));
System.out.println(instant);
```

<sup>*1) The `ChronoField` can be any time-**of-day** field, i.e. `HOUR_OF_DAY`, `CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY`, `MINUTE_OF_DAY`, `SECOND_OF_DAY`, `MILLI_OF_DAY`, `MICRO_OF_DAY`, or `NANO_OF_DAY`.*</sup>

*Output*

```
2020-01-11T23:00:00Z
```

---

If you want to retain the time zone offset, you need to use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) (or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)) instead of [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html):

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-01-12+01:00", formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
```

*Output (from both OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime)*

```
2020-01-12T00:00+01:00
2020-01-12+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter)` using the `Formatter` you've made above to give you a `LocalDate` instance.

`LocalDate` can then give you a `LocalDateTime` at any time in that day, but (for example) you can get [the start of day](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--) from it.

`LocalDateTime` has a [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-) method to give you an `Instant`.

`Instant` has a [`toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) method to get your `long`.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.  You'll end up throwing away the offset.

Comment: Fair do's.  `ZonedDate*` has the same methods and observes the offset.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy enough when you know how. The formatter we need is built in. There’s a complication in the fact that there isn’t a type to parse the string into, no `OffsetDate`. I present two options for tackling this.

```
    String s = "2020-01-12+01:00";

    TemporalAccessor parsed = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE.parse(s);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(parsed);
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(parsed);
    Instant result = date.atStartOfDay(offset).toInstant();

    System.out.println(result);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2020-01-11T23:00:00Z

We seldom need to use the `TemporalAccessor` interface directly, and it’s considered low-level. It also isn’t the only way to go here. The other good option is to define a default time of day so we can parse directly into an `Instant`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .toFormatter();
    Instant result = formatter.parse(s, Instant::from);
```

The result is the same as before.